# Create Check Constraint SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create three tables with check constraint but I'm receiving this error message

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed and An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

```
CREATE TABLE P(X INT); 
CREATE TABLE Q( a INT PRIMARY KEY, b INT, CONSTRAINT check_T CHECK ( b IN (SELECT c FROM Q)));
CREATE TABLE O (a INT, b INT, c INT, CONSTRAINT check_O CHECK( [fill-in] ));
```

Comment: I don't understand the error message fully or what to do to correct it

Comment: The error message is clear - you can't use a sub-query in a check constraint. And the error message is helpful as it explains you can use a scalar method e.g. a function. So write a function.

Comment: Or refactor your schema to enable you to use a Foreign Key constraint on Q.b instead of a CHECK constraint.  Using a CHECK constraint to make sure a value is in a list of valid values is _unusual_.

Comment: Change that first `CHECK` constraint to a foreign key constraint. @DaleK Scalar UDF in a check constraint is usually a bad idea and rarely necessary

Comment: @Charlieface - call me short-sighted but I often just answer the question asked rather than take a step back and see if there is a better overall solution :) my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 : using a foreign key :**

```
CREATE TABLE P(X INT); 
CREATE TABLE Q 
( a INT NOT NULL,
 b INT,
CONSTRAINT PK_a PRIMARY KEY (a)
CONSTRAINT check_T FOREIGN KEY (B)
    REFERENCES REFERENCES Q(c))
```

**Solution 2 : using a [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) ([not recommended](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12779/how-are-my-sql-server-constraints-being-bypassed)):**

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfCheck_T(
    @column --add the data type
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Q WHERE b = @column )
        return 'Success'
    return 'Failure'
END
```

Then :

```
ALTER TABLE Q
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT check_T
    CHECK (udfCheck_T(b) = 'True')
```